# Reference to text processing/editing with unix utilities

Tags: shell, unix, text-processing

I need to process/edit text files everyday on my unix system. I usually end up writing scripts in python for certain tasks like pasting columns in different files or extracting emails out of csv files. I know there is very useful and optimal utilities in the unix system that are going to be useful to me but I really don't know which. For example I know of, `paste`, `head`, `grep`, `cat`, `tac`, piping, output redirection. I know that `awk` is a great utility but I haven't used it much since it has many options. I would like to know what other utilities may be of use for text processing/editing and if there is any good reference of how to use them.

Comment: some more: `ls`, `tree`, `tail`, `sed`, `find`, `xargs`, `date` ...

Comment: and even more: `rev`, `sort`, `uniq`, `join`, `tr`, `fmt`, `pr`, `nl`, ... soooo many to choose from.

Comment: for curiosity sake, while unix tools are great and you can do tons of stuff with them, why is python not enough?

Comment: @rlazo Python is useful, it's just unix utilities are optimal, written in C, faster than it could ever be on Python, used for years, so I guess there is no need in writing tools that are already sitting on my system.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza unless you are doing some expensive processing, the difference between the two is not going to be that big (I/O would probably dominate the cost). You can do pretty cool stuff with unix commands (follow climagic in twitter and check http://www.commandlinefu.com/) but it can also get pretty cryptic to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider reading the following books - they go in depth on UNIX tools and "the UNIX way" of building complex tools from simple ones:

- ["The Unix Programming Environment"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unix_Programming_Environment) by Kernighan, Pike
- ["Unix Power Tools"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003302.do) by Peek et al.